# For what $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1+z)^n}$ convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For what $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1+z)^n}$ convergent?

I tried the ratio test, $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{z^{n+1}}{(1+z)^{n+1}}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^n}=\vert\frac{ z}{1+z}\vert$ I'm not sure what I can say about this now, since $z$ is complex.

Comment: The concept of radius of convergence is defined only for power series.

Comment: The idea of radius of convergence is generally applicable to power series, which this isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write $w=\frac{z}{1+z}$ you get the power series $\sum w^n$ which is (trivially) convergent for $|w|<1$.

So your series converges whenever $$\left|\frac{z}{z+1}\right|<1$$

Can you finish?

**HINT** $|z|<|1+z|\iff d(z,0)<d(z,-1)$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Let $(x + iy) = z$ and let $\overline{z} = (x - iy)$.  Then $(\overline{z+1}) = (\overline{z} + 1).$  Further, for any non-zero complex $t$, you have that $$(t\times \overline{t}) = |t|^2 ~~\text{ and you have that}~~\frac{1}{t} = \frac{\overline{t}}{t\times \overline{t}}.$$

Comment: @AColoredReptile Actually, while my previous comment may be helpful, I suggest that you give careful consideration to Tito Eliatron's *hint*.  Imagine the line segment $L$ joining $(0,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.  Now imagine the **perpendicular bisector** of line segment $L$.  From Geometry, you know that any point on the perpendicular bisector of $L$ **must be** equidistant from the two endpoints of line segment $L$.